# Generic asynctask for ws calls in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm using AsyncTask class to execute WS methods. I would like to have a generic async task class to call any method in the WS.

I create a set of classes that works fine but the problem is when I have to update the UI. I know I can create the async task with a reference to the Activity class and then execute the desired method, but what I want is the method to execute to be also a parameter.

Otherwise I have to implement a new class for each method which interacts with the UI because each action is different depending on the method.

Provably the solution is to use Listeners combined with parameters but I didn't find a complete example of how to use this.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30861384/3496570

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most close answer is [this](http://geekjamboree.wordpress.com/2011/11/22/asynctask-call-web-services-in-android/)

You can choose the method in the same UI which waits until the background process ends

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you cannot pass a method as a parameter, but you can pass an object that extends or implements an ancestor and overrides that method.  The Command pattern uses this concept (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

Here's an idea of the approach:

```
private static interface Command {
    public void execute();
}

public static final class MyWsCommand1 implements Command {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        // TODO your WS code 1
    }
}

public static final class MyWsCommand2 implements Command {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        // TODO your WS code 2
    }
}

private static class GenericAsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {

    private Command command;

    public GenericAsyncTask(Command command) {
        super();
        this.command = command;
    }

    @Override
    protected Result doInBackground(Params... params) {
        // TODO your code
        command.execute();
        // TODO your code
        return null;
    }

}

private GenericAsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> myAsyncTask1;
private GenericAsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> myAsyncTask2;
```

And use those in your code:

```
myAsyncTask1 = new GenericAsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>(new MyWsCommand1());
    myAsyncTask1.execute();
```

...

```
    myAsyncTask2 = new GenericAsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>(new MyWsCommand2());
    myAsyncTask2.execute();
```

Comment: Hi, 
Nice approach ... BUT ... how can you publish the progress using a dialog?

Answer (score 1):

by WS , you mean webservice?

asyncTask is not meant to be used for such long tasks . they are supposed to do small tasks . things that take (approx.) less than 5 seconds .

if you wish to do very long tasks , use a simple thread and consider putting it in a service.

also , in order to communicate with it , you can communicate with the service , and when you need to post something to the UI thread , use a handler .

Comment: Really? I was implementing it with an asyncTask because I thought it was the best option. So, you're suggesting to use a Thread, that's fine, but how can I use a Handler for the post procesing?

Comment: Using AsyncTask for long operations?  Well, your WS calls may not in fact be so long.  But that's not the point.  It is in fact important that you can quickly cancel and clean up the async task, say, from your activity's onPause().  If so, no problem.  Otherwise, I'd consider a Service for long background operations.

Comment: It's really a difference between a Service that outlives the Activity and some concurrency within the Activity. In the latter case, AsyncTask, threads handlers are all the same if implemented correctly.

Comment: there are many ways to achieve the same functionality without asyncTask . don't forget that if you wish to use multiple asyncTasks at the same time, don't use "execute" (as of 3.0, asyncTask runs on a single thread) . the question is how long is the process of using the WS .  anyway, if it's "too long" , consider using a thread . before you create the thread , create a handler (on the UI thread) and pass it to the thread so that it could send a message to the UI thread . here's a nice link about this: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

Answer (score 0):

I would use Async, and I did on a production implementation.  The issue you'll run into is doing more logic in the doInBackground because if you watch your debug build any time you see it say "Skipped X Frames" you may want to do a lot of post processing in doInBackground still.

Using an interface is the best approach, it's how I implemented my Async class. full.stack.ex hit the nail on the head with that answer.  That answer shows a clear, simple, powerful way to extend Async and use it for your purpose.