# Android generic Asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I currently have multiple activity that needs to perform an asynctask for http post and I wish to make the asynctask as another class file so that the different activity can call the asynctask to perform the http post request and onPostExecute, call the method httpResult(result) in the activity that called the asynctask. I have tried to pass the activity in but I am unable to call the method in onPostExecute. How can I do that?

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_MyActivity);

    //logic here...
    AsyncHttpPost asyncHttpPost = new AsyncHttpPost("someContent", this, dialog);
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    data.put("key", "value");
    try {
            asyncHttpPost.execute(data);
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void httpResult(String result) {
        //this method has to get called by asynctask to make changes to the UI
     }

}
```

AsyncHttpPost.java

```
public class AsyncHttpPost extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, String, String> {
String recvdjson;
String mData="";
private ProgressDialog dialog;
private Activity activity;


public AsyncHttpPost(String data, Activity activity, ProgressDialog dialog) {
    mData = data;
    this.activity = activity;
    this.dialog = dialog;
}

protected void onPreExecute()
{

    dialog.show();
}

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {

       //logic to do http request
           return "someStringResult";

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        activity.httpResult(result); //This line gives me error : The method httpResult(String) is undefined for the type Activity


    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code and explain the problem..

Comment: You should post your code to make it easier to solve your problem.

Comment: Edited my questions with example code

Comment: Remove the static identifier from the function `httpResult` so change `public static void httpResult(String result)` to `public void httpResult(String result)`

Comment: Sherif: Same error after I removed the static from the httpResult function

Comment: on your `onPostExecute`, try to cast the activity. it should look like this `((MyActivity) activity).httpResult(result);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an Interface called HttpResponseImpl in a seperate file and add the required method `httpResult`

```
interface HttpResponseImpl{
    public void httpResult(String result);
}
```

Now implement this interface by you `Activity` class

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements HttpResponseImpl{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_MyActivity);

    //logic here...
    AsyncHttpPost asyncHttpPost = new AsyncHttpPost("someContent", this, dialog);
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    data.put("key", "value");
    try {
            asyncHttpPost.execute(data);
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void httpResult(String result){
        //this method has to get called by asynctask to make changes to the UI
    }
}
```

And your AsyncHttpPost class would be.

```
public class AsyncHttpPost extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, String, String> {
String recvdjson;
String mData="";
private ProgressDialog dialog;
private HttpResponseImpl httpResponseImpl;


public AsyncHttpPost(String data, HttpResponseImpl httpResponseImpl, ProgressDialog dialog) {
    mData = data;
    this.httpResponseImpl = httpResponseImpl;
    this.dialog = dialog;
}

protected void onPreExecute()
{

    dialog.show();
}

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {

       //logic to do http request
           return "someStringResult";

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        httpResponseImpl.httpResult(result); 


    }
}
```

Implements this `HttpResponseImpl` interface with all you `Activity` class from which you want to do HttpRequest.

Comment: This would work for a single activity, but I have a few activities that would use this asynctask as well and it is not possible for me to list all, am I right?

Comment: My dear your approach is wrong you are passing an `Activity` class which doesn't have method `httpResult(String result)` by his own.

Comment: For your requirement you should have try call back mechanism or Observer Listener pattern.

Comment: Anieeh: Appreciate if you could provide code examples for me to try?

Answer (score 1):

**Generic AsyncTask Example**

Call it like

```
new RetrieveFeedTask(new OnTaskFinished()
        {
            @Override
            public void onFeedRetrieved(String feeds)
            {
                //do whatever you want to do with the feeds
            }
        }).execute("http://enterurlhere.com");
```

**RetrieveFeedTask.class**

```
class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    String HTML_response= "";

    OnTaskFinished onOurTaskFinished;


    public RetrieveFeedTask(OnTaskFinished onTaskFinished)
    {
        onOurTaskFinished = onTaskFinished;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]); // enter your url here which to download

            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            // open the stream and put it into BufferedReader
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                // System.out.println(inputLine);
                HTML_response += inputLine;
            }
            br.close();

            System.out.println("Done");

        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return HTML_response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String feed)
    {
        onOurTaskFinished.onFeedRetrieved(feed);
    }
}
```

**OnTaskFinished.java**

```
public interface OnTaskFinished
{
    public void onFeedRetrieved(String feeds);
}
```